# how to use shared objects in different spring projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jar

I have 2 projects that use an object that uses these:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.ronyt.common.model.enums.Hand;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.io.Serializable;
```

I have this object duplicated in both projects. How can I extract it to a single project and use it in the other two spring projects?

Comment: probably convert your project into a multi-module project, and the 3rd project will be a dependency to the other two projects and specified in the pom.xml

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I'll search how to convert it. I'm not that familiar with Spring.